# Bang's open question strengthening Tarski's planks problem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, open-problems, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

[Tarski's Planks problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_plank_problem),
solved by Thøger Bang in 1951, says (in a simplified $\mathbb{R}^2$ version) that it requires
"planks" (parallel strips) of total width $\ge d$ in order to completely cover
a disk of diameter $d$.
The last paragraph of Bang's short paper poses an open problem:

---

[image: Bang]

          

<sup>(Snapshot from Bang's paper.)</sup>

---

Does anyone know if this problem has been solved?
I am especially interested in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

> Bang, Thøger (1951), "[A solution of the 'plank problem'](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1951-0046672-4)", *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 2 (6): 990–993, doi:10.2307/2031721, [JSTOR 2031721](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2031721), MR 0046672.

Comment: I don't think it solves the problem, but it is discussed in Bezdek's paper, Tarski's plank problem revisited, available at http://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4637.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Great resource, thanks! "Recall that Ball ([2]) proved that such sum [of relative widths of the body]
should exceed $1$ in the case of centrally symmetric body $K$, while the general
case is still open."

Comment: It is open, as I know. Solved in partial cases, in particular for centrally  symmetric bodies (K. Ball).