# Plank invariant measures on convex bodies

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, convex-geometry, open-problems, convexity, geometric-measure-theory

Let $K\subset R^2$ be a *convex body*, i.e., a compact convex set with interior points. A *plank* $P$ is the region between a pair of parallel lines in $R^2$. Let us say that $P$ intersects $K$ *properly* provided that both boundary lines of $P$ intersect $K$.

> **Question:** Let $K\subset R^2$ be a convex body with diameter $d$. Suppose there exists a measure $\mu$ on $K$ such that  $\mu(P\cap K)$ is constant for all planks of some fixed width $0<h<d$ which properly intersect $K$. Must $K$ then be a disk?

A disk $D\subset R^2$ does indeed admit such a measure. Let $S\subset R^3$ be a sphere with $D$ as an equatorial disk, and $\mu$ be the measure on $D$ induced by the projection of $S$ (see the picture below which is from this paper of [Kupavskii and Pach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08111.pdf)). Then $\mu$ will be plank invariant due to the [Archimedes hatbox theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html).

[image: Induced plank invariant measure on the disk]

The motivation for the above question is that a positive answer here would yield a positive answer to this [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283109/converse-of-the-archimedean-property-of-the-sphere), on the *Converse of the Archimedean property of the sphere*, as follows.

Suppose that there exits a convex surface $S\subset R^3$ with the Archimedean slab invariant area property mentioned in the [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283109/converse-of-the-archimedean-property-of-the-sphere). Then the projection of $S$ into any plane would yield a convex body with the plank invariant property with respect to the induced measure. Hence the projection would be a disk, if the answer to the above question were yes, which would in turn imply that $S$ is a sphere (it is [well-known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-all-of-whose-projections-are-circles-or-can-we) that the sphere is the only convex surface with round projections).

For some results in the direction of the above problem see this paper of [Gardner](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102688294). Another nice paper discussing some relevant background and questions is the expository paper of [King](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/King609-628.pdf) in the Monthly. More references can be found in the recent paper of [Kupavskii and Pach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08111.pdf) mentioned above. Also see the answer to this [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6964/egalitarian-measures) asked earlier, and [another similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139876/do-the-interiors-of-curves-of-constant-width-admit-linear-measures?noredirect=1&lq=1) which has remained unanswered. Questions of this type  have  connections to Tarski's plank problem and an [open question of Bang](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218884/bangs-open-question-strengthening-tarskis-planks-problem).

Comment: this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6964/egalitarian-measures is closely related.